# Random Phase approximation (RPA) in nuclear physics

Tags: nuclear-physics

What does [RPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_phase_approximation) mean? What makes it significant to be used to determine nuclear transition strengths and how?

Comment: Do you have access to any nuclear physics textbooks?

Comment: yes, but they mostly do not discuss RPA in detail.

Comment: I recommend From Nucleons to Nuclei by Jouni Suhonen.

Comment: okay thanks i'll go through it. Could you also explain briefly in your words as to how RPA is important in determining nuclear transition strengths ?

Comment: I don't think I can give clear description of RPA, but hopefully someone else can. I would just be repeating what's in Suhonen's book.

Comment: okay..why is the theory called 'random phase' approx? what is the significance of the term phase?